# How to remove the gap of icon when float left in the relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to remove the gap on the left of button_history but it's not working.

i have tried to use `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` to align the button_history to the left but still not worked.

[The icon on the left has a gap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTt8N.png)

Below is my xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fireTopLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorDrowzyBg"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_close"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_close" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_history"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_list" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_countdown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="00:00"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I expect it have no gap on the **left button_history**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that the default behavior of Toolbars is to add white space between the border and where the RelativeLayout begins. To fix this add the following to your Toolbar.

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default toolbar add some white space so, to ignore or remove these white space we can add these line of code in toolbar in xml layout **app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"** and
 **app:contentInsetStart="0dp"**

**Full Code Is:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fireTopLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorDrowzyBg"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/action_bar"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_close"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_close" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_history"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_list" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_countdown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this attribute to your toolbar:

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```